# Randomly spawn UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

Wondering why this code is giving me the error, "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'CGPoint'". I want the smallDot to spawn in a random place on the screen when the whiteDot covers the smallDot.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

private var addOne = 0

func spawnRandomPosition() {

    let height = self.view!.frame.height
    let width = self.view!.frame.width

    let randomPosition = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height),
                                 y: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width))   

return smallDot.center = randomPosition 
 }

 @IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                              y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if (WhiteDot.frame.contains(smallDot.frame) && smallDot.image != nil) {
        smallDot.image = nil;
        addOne += 1
        score.text = "\(addOne)"
    smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition() //this is line giving error//
    }

    }


        }
```

[image]

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: `spawnRandomPosition()` doesn't return anything, so you are trying to assign smallDot to void. Set the return value and provide a valid return statement

Comment: Tell us which lines are giving you the errors, and what is the exact text of the error messages?

Comment: Updated the return value still getting error on last line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value from the method. You need to return `CGPoint` in  order to use it in your `handlePan:` method.Define function return value as `CGPoint` and return your calculated random position.

```
func spawnRandomPosition() -> CGPoint  {

    let height = self.view!.frame.height
    let width = self.view!.frame.width

    let randomPosition = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: height),
                             y: CGFloat(arc4random()).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: width))   

    return randomPosition 
}
```

Comment: "Cannot convert value of type 'CGPoint' to type 'UIImageView'.

Comment: in your handlePan use it as smallDot.center = spawnRandomPosition(). Clean and rebuild if required.

Comment: Tried that but image ins't spawning in a random place on the image view.

Answer (score 1):

It gives the error because `spawnRandomPosition` has no return value. If you fix it to return the coordinate you generate, you will also likely need to assign that to the image view's coordinates.

See the apple docs for the proper syntax for a returning function. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: Keep trying to understand the error messages (they usually make sense). If you get stumped give the location and error message.

Comment: Post your updated code at the bottom of your question under the label `##Edit`

Comment: @ZDP the function signature needs to specify the return value: `func spawnRandomPosition() -> typeToReturn { ...` but your return statement is trying to return a CGPoint, which is not a UIImageView, and smallDot is, so try setting `smallDot.center` to `spawnRandomPosition()` without setting its image to nil.